# postgres 'only' shows numbers with comma seperator, even if data is saved without

Tags: postgresql

my postgres shows me only comma separated number values like:

[image]

even when the original number comes without the separator.

`lc_numeric` shows me `German_Germany.1252`, which seems to be right.

So when the data is saved correctly, where can I change the format of the shown output?

Comment: what data type is the column? maybe the UI client is formatting it for you. Try retrieving some values using the CLI instead of the UI client

Comment: Check the configuration of the SQL client you are using. And formatting you see is applied by the application displaying the value - in your case your SQL client

Comment: thx, it was the ui client. (DBeaver in my example https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/2334)